# App engine - check to see if a property exists within Expando class

Tags: python, google-app-engine, expando

What is a good way to check to see if a property is populated in an expando class (Python for App Engine)

Can I do:

```
if Expando_class_name.property_name_to_check:
    do = someStuff
```

Or is that going to give me an error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `hasattr`:

```
if hasattr(expando_instance, 'foo'):
  # Do something with expando_instance.foo
```

Answer (score 2):

A better way is to use  the dynamic_properties method.

```
if 'foo' in entity.dynamic_properties():  pass
```