# check to see if a property exists within a C# Expando class

Tags: c#, dynamic, expandoobject

I would like to see if a property exist in a C# Expando Class.

much like the [hasattr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339032/app-engine-check-to-see-if-a-property-exists-within-expando-class) function in python. I would like the c# equalant for hasattr.

something like this...

```
if (HasAttr(model, "Id"))
{
  # Do something with model.Id
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect if a property exists on an ExpandoObject?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839598/how-to-detect-if-a-property-exists-on-an-expandoobject)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try:

```
dynamic yourExpando = new ExpandoObject();
if (((IDictionary<string, Object>)yourExpando).ContainsKey("Id"))
{
    //Has property...
}
```

An ExpandoObject explicitly implements `IDictionary<string, Object>`, where the Key is a property name. You can then check to see if the dictionary contains the key. You can also write a little helper method if you need to do this kind of check often:

```
private static bool HasAttr(ExpandoObject expando, string key)
{
    return ((IDictionary<string, Object>) expando).ContainsKey(key);
}
```

And use it like so:

```
if (HasAttr(yourExpando, "Id"))
{
    //Has property...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to vcsjones answer it will be even nicer to:

```
private static bool HasAttr(this ExpandoObject expando, string key)
{
    return ((IDictionary<string, Object>) expando).ContainsKey(key);
}
```

and then:

```
dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
expando.Name = "Test";

var result = expando.HasAttr("Name");
```

Comment: It would perhaps be nice, but C# won't allow an extension method on a dynamic object.  See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501773/how-to-apply-an-extension-method-on-the-object-having-the-type-of-expandoobject].

Comment: What about adding a dynamic method named HasAttr to the expando object? Something like this: expando.HasAttr = new Func<bool>((string key) => ((IDictionary<string, Object>) expando).ContainsKey(key));