# How to know if a given object contains any dynamic property?

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection

I m in middle of developing an application using third party api. They have provided a sample app to demonstrate the API. In the sample app there is a propertygrid which displays all the properties of the selected object.In the sample app I could see a propert lets say "X" but programmatically I am not able to access it by putting dot(.) after the object variable. I also used reflection to get the properties but no success. Someone suggested that it might be a dynamic property. I found no way to check if the given object or any of the memberof that object is dynamic?

Please suggest a way to access that property.

PropertGrid control is able to display the above mentioned property and also allows to change the value but this property is not accessible pro-grammatically.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044465/check-to-see-if-a-property-exists-within-a-c-sharp-expando-class/12044495#12044495

Comment: Thanks vcsjones. But no success.

Answer (score 1):

The way to solve this problem is to look directly at the generated IL of the type that you know has dynamic properties. There you will find that such a property is represented simply as an *object* type, but also all of its components are decorated with the *DynamicAttribute* attribute.

This attribute is put in place by the compiler itself, and can not be used by the developer. Thus, the only thing you need to do is to check if a property is decorated with the *DynamicAttribute* attribute.

To see this, take a look at the following IL code for the **IamDynamic** property's Get accessor method, which we will use later for testing purposes.

```
.method public hidebysig specialname instance object 
      get_IamDynamic() cil managed

.custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
.param [0]
.custom instance void [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DynamicAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 

.maxstack  1
.locals init (object V_0)
IL_0000:  ldarg.0
IL_0001:  ldfld      object Testing.TestClass::'<IamDynamic>k__BackingField'
IL_0006:  stloc.0
IL_0007:  br.s       IL_0009
IL_0009:  ldloc.0
IL_000a:  ret
```

You can easily notice the line where the *DynamicAttribute* is used, indicating that this is a dynamic declaration. We can now discover all the dynamic properties by using the following extension method.

```
public static class DynamicExtension
{
    public static void GetDynamicProperties(this Type source)
    {
        source.GetProperties()
              .Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes().OfType<DynamicAttribute>().Any())
              .ToList()
              .ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Name));
    }
}
```

This class, that was mentioned above will be tested for dynamic properties.

```
class TestClass
{
    public dynamic IamDynamic { get; set; }        
    public object IamNotDynamic { get; set; }
    public dynamic IamAlsoDynamic { get; set; }
}
```

Once you execute the following lines of code, you will see that only the two dynamic properties are displayed.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        typeof(TestClass).GetDynamicProperties();

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```